# Snake pop() : it disappear

Tags: c++

since my last topic is full of edited versions and not very clear at all, and since I changed a lot of things and that I now understood how I could make it, I'm asking a new question about my snake : why does my snake disappear since when I call advanceStep(), yes it pop one element but right after it push_back another one?
Thanks for your help, I will have a better attitude. (Through @Jason C, asking somebody to give up, or say to him that I stole somebody's code, or that this is a homework, should also get a better attitude).
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <deque>

void advanceStep();

sf::Event event;
/*sf::Clock clockSnake;
sf::Time elapse;*/

sf::Vector2i direction(0, 0);


class SnakeBlock
{
public:

sf::Texture texture;
sf::Sprite snakeblock;
int dir;
int lastX, lastY;
};

std::deque<SnakeBlock> Snake;

int main()
{
//elapse = clockSnake.getElapsedTime();

sf::Music epicMusic;
epicMusic.openFromFile("epicmusic.wav");
epicMusic.play();

SnakeBlock snakeHead;
snakeHead.texture.loadFromFile("spritesheetsnake.png", sf::IntRect(0,0,20,22));
snakeHead.snakeblock.setTexture(snakeHead.texture);
SnakeBlock snakeBody1;
snakeBody1.snakeblock.setTexture(*(snakeHead.snakeblock.getTexture()));
SnakeBlock snakeBody2;
snakeBody2.snakeblock.setTexture(*(snakeHead.snakeblock.getTexture()));

Snake.push_back(snakeHead);
Snake.push_back(snakeBody1);
Snake.push_back(snakeBody2);

Snake[2].snakeblock.setPosition(500,350);
Snake[1].snakeblock.setPosition(475, 338);
Snake[0].snakeblock.setPosition(450, 316);

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1028,768), "SFML Snake");
window.setFramerateLimit(20);
while(window.isOpen())
{
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
            epicMusic.stop();
            window.close();
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }

    }

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
    {
            direction.x = -1;
            advanceStep();
            for(int i = 1; i < Snake.size(); i++)
            {
                Snake[i].snakeblock.setPosition(Snake[i+1].snakeblock.getPosition().x-20, Snake[i+1].snakeblock.getPosition().y);
            }
    }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    {
            direction.x = 1;
            advanceStep();
            for(int j = 1; j < Snake.size(); j++)
            {
                Snake[j].snakeblock.setPosition(Snake[j+1].snakeblock.getPosition().x+20, Snake[j+1].snakeblock.getPosition().y);
            }
    }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
    {
            direction.y = -1;
            advanceStep();
            for(int l = 1; l < Snake.size(); l++)
            {
                Snake[l].snakeblock.setPosition(Snake[l+1].snakeblock.getPosition().x, Snake[l+1].snakeblock.getPosition().y-22);
            }
    }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
    {
            direction.y = 1;
            advanceStep();
            for(int o = 1; o < Snake.size(); o++)
            {
                Snake[o].snakeblock.setPosition(Snake[o+1].snakeblock.getPosition().x, Snake[o+1].snakeblock.getPosition().y+22);
            }
    }
    window.clear(sf::Color::Red);
    for(unsigned int m = 0; m < Snake.size(); m++)
    {
        window.draw(Snake[m].snakeblock);
    }
    window.display();
}
return 0;

}

void advanceStep()
{
sf::Vector2f headpos;
headpos.x = Snake[0].snakeblock.getPosition().x;
headpos.y = Snake[0].snakeblock.getPosition().y;

headpos.x += 22 * direction.x;
headpos.y += 22 * direction.y;

SnakeBlock element;
element.snakeblock.setPosition(headpos);

Snake.push_front(element);
Snake.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to format your code.

Comment: Look, this type of questions requires too much time digging in someone else's code; effectively you're asking to find bugs in the logic which isn't really related to C++.

Comment: WHy does your for loop for the actual drawing start at 1 instead of 0? for(unsigned int m = 1; m < Snake.size(); m++)

Comment: Its not too much digging seriously, on the other thread people helped me a lot. :)

Comment: doctorlove, thanks I had seen that just after made my post so I edited it just before you posted :p

Comment: The `+1`s in your loops cause you to index outside the bounds of the snake deque. Your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Fixed it and the snake still disappear

Comment: @user2687718 `SnakeBlock element;` never gets assigned a texture

Comment: thanks I had forgotten that, i'm so dumb sometimes... :)

Comment: @m0skit0: That's not right. The whole post isn't formatted.

Comment: @user2687718: Consider deleting every line of code that is clearly *unrelated* to the problem. Is `case sf::Event::Closed: epicMusic.stop();` an important step in redrawing?

Comment: those are only 3 lines, if you go through the code you know they are not important :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks as if you're accessing `Snake` out of bounds:

```
        for(int i = 1; i < Snake.size(); i++)
        {
            ...setPosition(Snake[i+1]....
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed size to size minus one, through the problem is more located at the pop() in the advanceStep function as I said because the snake still disappear. :(